# Calling a Web Service Built in Net beans through firefox extension?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have created a simple web service in java using netbeans and  jBoss application server now i want to use that webservice to be called by a firefox extension ie. on a button click of my firefox extension toolbar ..

Web service Url::::**http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldDemo/HelloWorld?wsdl**
Method:: "hello" that takes only one prameter that is a string value and return string.

can u suggest me the way of calling that webservice using firefox extension

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could get inspiration watching the code of [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/)?

Comment: I dont know i am a newbie to the firefox extensions and webservices so i am not getting the code of this extension, how it works and all

Comment: i Just need the way to call Webservice created in netbeans either via java script or bu any other means though firefox extension..